# Why there are no constraints on TStartup in Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp Start<TStartup>

Tags: c#, owin, type-constraints

I was playing with a project. And the following line piqued my interest where `Startup` is a custom class

`Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);`

And when I examine the class `Startup`, I've found out that it did not inherit from any class or interface. And after that I looked into `WebApp.Start` and there was no constraints on `TStartup`. So in place of `Startup` on the above line of code, I can even write `int` and it compiles just fine. However in runtime it gives the following error:

> "The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.\r\n - No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":""

So it requires a `Configuration` method which in fact exists in the original `Startup` class. Then my question is that why did they not use an interface with a `Configuration` method?